# Is it possible to translate a SAS infile statement into R code?

Tags: r, sas, file-io

My knowledge of SAS is inexistent, and I usually work in R and Stata. Recently I downloaded a dataset that is publicly available from the Brazilian government, and for some reason they made it available in raw format with a SAS script to read it in:

```
DATA DOM (COMPRESS = YES);
INFILE "...¥T_DOMICILIO_S.txt" LRECL = 164 MISSOVER;     

INPUT  @001 TIPO_REG    $2.   /* TIPO DE REGISTRO  */
       @003 COD_UF      $2.   /* CﾓDIGO DA UF      */         
       @005 NUM_SEQ     $3.   /* NﾚMERO SEQUENCIAL */
       @008 NUM_DV      $1.   /* DV DO SEQUENCIAL  */                

…Etc etc…

RUN;
```

Is it possible to "translate this statement into an equivalent for r? If so, which function should I be looking for?

Comment: All the lines after `INPUT` seem to be for each variable in the format `@start_column variable_name variable_format /* comment describing variable */` You could probably translate this to a `?read.fwf` call in R. See here for more info on what this text file means: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/library/nesug00/bt3002.pdf

Comment: See the link at the bottom of my aswer for Damico's page entitled "analyze the censo demografico no brasil (censo) with r and monetdb".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an app for that! Well an R package, anyway, [`SAScii`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SAScii/index.html), brought to you by the indomitable Anthony Damico. It has two functions: `parse.SAScii` and `read.SAScii`. I've used it with great success on US gummint CDC files.

```
install.packages("SAScii")
library(SAScii)

> parse.SAScii("test.sas")
   varname width char divisor
1 TIPO_REG     2 TRUE       1
2   COD_UF     2 TRUE       1
3  NUM_SEQ     3 TRUE       1
4   NUM_DV     1 TRUE       1
Warning message:
In readLines(sas_ri) : incomplete final line found on 'test.sas'
```

--
Then you will need to use read.SAScii for the second step, but you did not offer an appropriate test file for that test.

The input file, 'test.sas' was:

```
DATA DOM (COMPRESS = YES);
INFILE "...¥T_DOMICILIO_S.txt" LRECL = 164 MISSOVER;     

INPUT  @001 TIPO_REG    $2.   /* TIPO DE REGISTRO  */
       @003 COD_UF      $2.   /* CﾓDIGO DA UF      */         
       @005 NUM_SEQ     $3.   /* NﾚMERO SEQUENCIAL */
       @008 NUM_DV      $1.   /* DV DO SEQUENCIAL  */                

RUN;
```

If you view the ["twotorials" on Youtube by Anthony Damico](http://www.twotorials.com/) or go to [his website](http://www.asdfree.com/) you can see why I used the word "indomitable".

Answer (score 9):

the other responses to your question are better because they are more general.  but you are asking specifically about ibge's pesquisa orçamentos familiares..  and i have already written code to import *all* of the 2002-2003 and 2008-2009 directly into R without further ado.  :)  just follow the directions at the top, run the download script, and everything will be loaded into R correctly.

https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/tree/master/Pesquisa%20de%20Orcamentos%20Familiares

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/pesquisa%20de%20orcamentos%20familiares%20%28pof%29

Comment: How's that for service, @GuiGuilhermeKenjiChihaya? A chat box popped up as I was looking at one of Anthony's pages and I told him about your question, and he comes back with the complete answer.

Comment: That is indeed great service. I greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

SAS has many more input options than R, so sometimes it may be difficult to make direct translations; but you might consider looking at [the SAScii package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SAScii/index.html) to help you create a call to `read.fwf`